# Angular 7: can't find module. can't resolve 'underscore'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am working on angular 7 project. I tried to install

```
 npm install --save @types/underscore
```

and i get following errors:

> npm WARN @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of
>   @angular/common@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.5
>   requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/cdk@6.4.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0
>   <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
>   yourself. npm WARN @angular/cdk@6.4.7 requires a peer of
>   @angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN @angular/material@6.4.7
>   requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/material@6.4.7 requires a peer of
>   @angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/platform-server@6.1.10 requires a peer of
>   @angular/animations@6.1.10 but none is installed. You must install
>   peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN @angular/platform-server@6.1.10
>   requires a peer of @angular/common@6.1.10 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/platform-server@6.1.10 requires a peer of
>   @angular/compiler@6.1.10 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN @angular/platform-server@6.1.10
>   requires a peer of @angular/core@6.1.10 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/platform-server@6.1.10 requires a peer of
>   @angular/platform-browser@6.1.10 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/platform-server@6.1.10 requires a peer of
>   @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@6.1.10 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN codelyzer@4.3.0
>   requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta
>   <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
>   yourself. npm WARN codelyzer@4.3.0 requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   @angular/animations@6.1.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@6.1.10 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm
>   WARN @angular/router@6.1.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@6.1.10
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN @angular/router@6.1.10 requires a peer of
>   @angular/common@6.1.10 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN @angular/router@6.1.10 requires a peer
>   of @angular/platform-browser@6.1.10 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN ngx-toastr@9.1.0 requires
>   a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install
>   peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN ngx-toastr@9.1.0 requires a peer
>   of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN ngx-toastr@9.1.0 requires a peer of
>   @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> - @types/underscore@1.8.9 added 1 package from 5 contributors and audited 40215 packages in 20.546s found 0 vulnerabilities

after it i get this error:

```
./src/app/services/pager.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'underscore' in 'e:\xampp\htdocs\testapp\src\app\services
```

Please help me.

Comment: @veben i am using this command `ng new testapp`. It running before i run this command `npm install --save @types/underscore`

Comment: @veben I am using `import * as _ from 'underscore';` but i gives an error.

Answer (score 5):

you need to  install underscore into dependencies and @types/underscore into devDependencies.

```
npm i underscore --save
npm i @types/underscore --save-dev
```

then you can use it.

Comment: After installing i am still getting this error `ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[QuickWorkerListComponent -> PagerService]:`

Comment: this error has nothing with underscore.  this means that your PagerService is not added to your Module Providers

Comment: Open new question and we will try to help. this question is about underscore.